# Enable automatic redirect on POST request with HttpClient

Tags: android, redirect, post, httpclient

I have an app that should run on Android, hopefully starting from 2.3 to 4.4.2.

I am trying to make a HTTP POST request with Apache HttpClient, and I want to enable auto-redirect.
I already made a code working in pure Java, with HttpClient library installed. It uses `setRedirect(new LaxRedirectStrategy)`.

Homever, it isn't accepted in my Android project.

And none of the solutions I've encountered on the Internet is working :

```
httpclient.getParams().setParameter(ClientPNames.HANDLE_REDIRECTS, true);

httpclient.getParams().setParameter("http.protocol.allow-circular-redirects", true);

HttpClientParams.setRedirecting(httpclient.getParams(), true);

...
```

Eclipse doesn't recognize the setRedirectStrategy() method, although the Android 4.4.2 library is bundled with my project.

If I had time, I would try to handle the redirection myself or, better, switch to HttpUrlConnection which seems a lot better. But this is a huge private library I made for a lot of webservices I have to access, and I don't have time to do this now. Is there a way to enable auto-redirect in a simple way ?

The entire code looks like this :

```
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
client.setCookieStore(cookies);
client.getParams().setParameter(ClientPNames.HANDLE_REDIRECTS, true);
client.getParams().setParameter("http.protocol.allow-circular-redirects", true);
HttpClientParams.setRedirecting(client.getParams(), true);
client.getParams().setParameter("http.protocol.version",
            HttpVersion.HTTP_1_0) ;
```

Comment: This is not an acceptable answer to my problem, in my opinion, but I managed to get what I wanted by handling the redirect myself, firing a get method myself with the same client.
I'm not marking this as solved because I have to write a library to access a Shibboleth website soon, and I can't imagine having to handle redirects in this case. The Objective-C version is already very long, this would make the Android version ten times longer !

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem ( i now use volley library for REST API) but i think adding this may help:

`httpclient.getParams().setParameter("http.protocol.version",
                HttpVersion.HTTP_1_0)`

versions seemed to work differently between android and java.

Let me know if that works.God Bless.

Jonny 2 Plates

Comment: I saw people who say this helps, but I didn't know whether it should be put with another 'setParameter' or alone. Do you need others to enable redirecting ?

Comment: OK insert this in your code but code you paste your full code so i and the rest of the community can see what you are doing.

Comment: I added your line of code with the 3 above, and it didn't work.

See my code above.

Comment: place client.getParams().setParameter("http.protocol.version",
            HttpVersion.HTTP_1_0) ; before the HttpClientParams.setRedirecting() method is called!